Is it possible to have Bun bundle my TypeScript on file save in VS Code?
Is it possible to have Bun bundle my TypeScript on file save in VS Code?
The guide says I can call bun run index.ts in the command line and add it to the package.json like so but I don't know how to make it run on save.
{
  "name": "quickstart",
  "module": "index.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "bun run index.ts"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bun": "^1.0.0"
  }
}

UPDATE:
I have been calling bun run start and bun run index.ts but there is also another command, bun bun.build.js that may be related.

You could try bun --watch mode https://bun.sh/docs/runtime/hot
bun run --watch index.ts
If that doesn't work
Reading from : Running npm Command on File Save
You might be able to using something like: npm-watch
  "watch": {
    "start": "{src,test}/*.ts"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "bun run index.ts",
    "watch": "npm-watch"
  },


Hi Henry. I tried the package.json options and I don't see any changes. The command line might work. I would probably need to run that manually at startup.. vscode has a .vscode/tasks.json option that sometimes has worked before in other projects.

@1.21gigawatts - I have updated the package.json, I forgot to include the "watch" script - assuming you want to use npm-watch package.
Bun does have the hot reloader and would likely be a better choice.
You can mitigate needing to type in --watch, if it, works by changing your start script to:
"start": "bun --watch run index.ts",
Then you can do bun run start to execute your start script in watch mode.
From my understanding you just want your bun to 'restart' when you save, to circumvent needing to constantly type bun run start. And --watch mode will do that
