How do I attach things to do when I save or build in VS Code?
I would like to have things run when I run build (Command + Shift + B) or on save (Command + S) in VS Code.
I would like TypeScript to run and I'd like Bun to run and I'd like Node.js to run after that and then I want to launch a browser window.
In VS Code I found a run and debug panel and it lists a lot of options I don't understand where the option is to run a list of things or commands. In my project I have tsconfig.json, package.json, tasks.json, package-lock.json, bun.build.js, and launch.json and some of them have script values with commands in them. What do I do to simplify this?
Here is my tasks.json:
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "typescript",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
            "option": "watch",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc-watch"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "label": "tsc: watch - tsconfig.json"
        },
    ]
}

In the latest release of vscode there is an option called, Code Actions on Save. This sounds like what I want but it only has a few options listed.

did you really have to post both this and https://stackoverflow.com/q/78703696/11107541 ?

@starball they are slightly different questions. one is specific to bun and this one is generic.

To attach things to save or build actions, you could try this:

Create/ Update 'tasks.json'

// Inside .vscode/tasks.json, update or add the following
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "compile TypeScript",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "tsc",
            "problemMatcher": ["$tsc"],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "run Bun",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "bun build.js",
            "dependsOn": "compile TypeScript"
        },
        {
            "label": "run Node.js",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "node your_script.js",
            "dependsOn": "run Bun"
        }
    ]
}


Create/ Update 'launch.json'

// Inside .vscode/launch.json , add or update the following
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Browser",
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "preLaunchTask": "run Node.js"
        }
    ]
}


Configure Auto Save in 'settings.json'

// Inside settings.json, you can add or update the following code
{
    "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
}

Doing all this will launch a browser window after you save or build

I have a feeling your isDefault is on the wrong task

@starball I posted my tasks.json from another project. It has isDefault in the same place. Is there somewhere else it should be located?

@starball interestingly enough, the isDefault flag set to true was problematic in my case. When I attempted to build, vscode popped up a dialog asking which one. It also started Java for some reason. I set one task to false and it seems to fix the issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78711660/why-did-java-start-when-i-built-my-vscode-project

@starball I think you are correct. Is default needs to be put on the last task to run so that any task that it depends on will run first? Moving the group section to Bun causes TSC to run first and Bun second. I removed the node.js for now and set the prelaunch in the launch.json to run Bun. The browser isn't launching but the other parts are working.

I had to put the path to the browser in the launch.json. The browser now launches when I click the Start Debugging button from the Debug panel. It also runs the tasks. If I use the keyboard shortcut ctrl + shift + B the tasks are run and vscode puts a message in the footer, Launch Browser (myproject) - Select and start debug configuration. If I then click that the command palette shows all the launch configs. If I click on one of those it creates a new instance of the browser.

Quick followup - Is there a way to get this to run on save? It works on build but not on save. If I use CMD + SHIFT + B it will run on build.
